# Why does my music not play first time?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, mpmusicplayercontroller

I have this code:

```
[self.musicPlayer stop];
[self.musicPlayer setQueueWithQuery:persistentQuery];
[self.musicPlayer play];
```

But for some reason, you only hear the first split second of a song the first time. Then the second time, you hear the song. Doing a sort of patch-fix with:

```
[self.musicPlayer stop];
[self.musicPlayer setQueueWithQuery:persistentQuery];
[self.musicPlayer play];
[self.musicPlayer stop];
[self.musicPlayer play];
```

doesn't work - this only makes it play the first split second every time.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem in that a MusicPlayer object would not play when the play method was first called. I found I had to setup the musicPlayer object earlier in the app life cycle i.e. set it up before you require it.

Comment: Your answer does not give any reasons.